# How to connect the field with another field in one table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use model first.

entity:

```
class User
{
Guid UserId{get;set;}
Guid RefererUserId {get;set;}
User RefereUser {get;set;}
}
```

Datacontext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.ReferrerUser)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferrerUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        }
 public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I initilize database:

```
MembershipCreateStatus Status;
Membership.CreateUser("Demo", "123456", "demo@demo.com", null, null, true, out Status);

Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
Roles.AddUserToRole("Demo", "Admin");
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var a = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == "demo@demo.com").FirstOrDefault();
a.MoneyRUB = 100;
a.MoneyUSD = 100;
db.SaveChanges();
```

I get error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE
>   constraint "User_ReferrerUser". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Kamikaze", table "dbo.Users", column 'UserId'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making `RefererUserId` nullable (i.e. `Guid?`, not `Guid`). Otherwise, it would not be possible to insert the first user.

You also need to change `HasRequired` to `HasOptional` to make the model aware of the fact that there may not be a `RefererUser`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021125/335858) for details on setting up optional links in code first.

Comment: I get error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ReferrerUserId', table 'Kamikaze.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @simplydenis Obviously, that's the problem: you need to make `ReferrerUserId` nullable, re-generate your DDL, and use it to modify your database schema.

Comment: I cheked database. it is established that `ReferrerUserId` can not be null

Comment: @simplydenis Do you know how to make it nullable in the database?

Comment: I removed the link and had the resolution to null.

Comment: @simplydenis Is it working now with the field allowing nulls, or is it still not working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11652/discussion-between-simply-denis-and-dasblinkenlight)